# Transit visa required or not for DEL-LHR-DUB-YYZ

Tags: visas, transit, london, dublin

I ( an Indian passport holder) is planning to travel from Delhi,India to Toronto,Canada,via British Airways,with two stops at London & Ireland.

DEL (10:25) - LHR ( 13:55)
LHR ( 18:10) - DUB (19:35)
DUB (13:30) to YYz( 16) - next day.

The first layover is at Heathrow airport ( change plane from terminal 2 to terminal 5) with a layover of 2 hours 45 mins.

The second layover is at Dublin airport ( same terminal-2) with a layover of around 17 hours.

The second and third planes are being operated by Air Lingus

I am unable to souce whether I require a transit visa or not ? I am traveling to Canada ona student visa .

Can some one please help me , please, do i need a transit visa or not ?

Comment: @mlc The answers in that question are quite confusing and contradict each other :/

Comment: Still not clear, can any one please clarify this ?

Comment: The way around questions with confusing answers is to ask for clarification there, not to ask the same question again.

Comment: You need a standard UK visitor visa for this journey. This question is not the same as the previous question as the other question has 2 hour layover at Dublin while you have overnight 17 hour layover with a date change and thus need to enter Ireland. If you didn't have the LHR-DUB sector, which causes the most confusion, you would have required a visitor visa from Ireland. You need a visa which enables you to enter both the UK and Ireland, and is a standard UK visitor visa. You can confirm at both these websites:

Comment: https://www.irishimmigration.ie/at-the-border/transit-including-transfer-visa-advice/

https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/republic_of_ireland

Comment: Thanks alot Thomas for helping out